# VBA code to refresh format as table filter in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a format of table which is with filters and I made the filter to filter all the table based on the cells in column D3 that with value not blank. Now I am trying to make the filter work automatically based on any change on the list on cell G1.

I tried to use the pivot table but this did not work, as this type of table is not part of pivot table (formatted as table).

What is the correct code that can be used for such sorting?
The sheet is Sheet 1, the table named (PT).

Comment: no distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)), so leave out the begging and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will be activated only if the value in G1 is changed.

Open VBE using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, open "Sheet 1" module and paste the given code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo errH
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("G1")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        'Put here things that you want to be done if G1 value is changed
        'For example:
        MsgBox "G1 was changed."

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    Exit Sub
errH:
    MsgBox ("Error number: " & Err.Number & ". Description: " & Err.Description)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

You can test it - just change the G1 value and you will see that it works.

However, I do not understand your explanation about what you want to filter. But whatever it is, just put the code in the place which I identified and remove that `MsgBox`.

Comment: many thanks my friend, it helps a lot. I really appreciate it.

Comment: this help in part of my question and the other part is also found  as shown in below.

Comment: @NabilAmer what is actually missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim criteriaparameter As String
Dim criteriavalue As String
    On Error GoTo errH
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("G1")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        criteriaparameter = ActiveSheet.Range("J1").Value
        criteriavalue = ">=" & criteriaparameter

        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$8:$L$8").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=criteriavalue, _
        Operator:=xlAnd


        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    Exit Sub
errH:
    MsgBox ("Error number: " & Err.Number & ". Description: " & Err.Description)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```